# About PDF vertical sliding from page to page in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf

I am work on an app that can make PDF vertical sliding in iOS using `CGPDFDocumentRef`.
Now i can display one page PDF perfectly, but I don't know how can make it vertical sliding from page to page.

Can anyone help me? Give me an idea or sample，thank you

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Are you really looking for *vertical* sliding? That's the behavior of both UIWebView and QuickLook.framework on iOS. If you are referring to *horizontal* scrolling, check out one of the frameworks at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801358/pdf-parsing-library-for-ios

Answer (score 1):

add UIWebView in WebViewViewController.xib and connect that.Implement same as i have posted.

```
@interface WebViewViewController : UIViewController<TapDetectingWindowDelegate>
{


}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *mWebView;

@end



@implementation WebViewViewController
@synthesize mWebView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"EventHandlingiPhoneOS" 
                                                     ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


     [mWebView loadRequest:request];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the best PDF library you could integrate and implement PDF view horizontally.

https://github.com/vfr/Reader

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `UIWebView` for showing the PDF file?

It is very simple and easy to use it!

However, if you really want to make your custom viewer, you can use `UIScrollView` for it.

like this:

```
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,640)];
[self.view addSubview:scroll];
view1.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,640);
view2.frame = CGRectMake(0,320,320,640);
view3.frame = CGRectMake(0,640,320,640);
[scroll addSubview:view1];
[scroll addSubview:view2];
[scroll addSubview:view3];
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 960);
[scroll release];
```